# What is the current state of affairs of SpellJammer?

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons, spelljammer

Is there an expectation of anything happing with it in the future?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's been nothing announced from WotC, so my guess is that we won't see much. It's entirely possible that they'd be interested in publishing a *Dungeon* article on the setting, though.

Answer (score 5):

Spelljamming ships have appeared in Living Forgotten Realms adventures (I think there's a sunken one that the players can rescue in Core2-2, Rising of the Dark) as well as the Plane Above and the Plane Below sourcebooks. The Rock of Bral itself is still one of the tears of Selune.

There's still no official word on a return of the Spelljammer setting or not.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know they are holding on to the licencing agreement at WotC which may mean that they want to do something with it some day.  But since they've announced that Ravenloft is going to be their next campaign setting (released summer 2011), the best we can hope for, at least for a couple of years, are web enhancements and sidebars in publications.

I assume the reason we haven't seem more SJ is because of the Gammaworld release that is right around the corner.  SJ is the closest thing D&D has to sci-fi and I can see how they wouldn't want to put too much more energy into non traditional fantasy, especially with the Dark Sun release this summer.