# Will the SpellJammer campaign setting be updated to the 4e ruleset?

Tags: dnd-4e, spelljammer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the current state of affairs of SpellJammer?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/693/what-is-the-current-state-of-affairs-of-spelljammer)

I enjoyed playing in the Spelljammer universe - anyone know if there are plans to update it with the newer ruleset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For as far that I know, Wizards of the Coast have no intention to cover the Spelljammer setting.

The only content that I may point you to is that published with the **Manual of the Planes** (Spelljammer ships).

Comment: Did they explicitly say they're not doing spelljammer somewhere?

Comment: That's the tricky thing about it. I wasn't able to find any reference about Wizards intention to NOT cover Spelljammer: I simply found NO intention in covering it. I simply gathered opinions on the net which, of course, don't contribute to a real answer but is our best guess so far.

Comment: Knowing Wizards, I'm sure at some point they will cover it, if only to milk every last possible dollar out of the product line as they possibly can.